# Finite dimensional subspace and distance

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\cdot \|)$ be an infinite dimensional normed vector space and $V \subseteq X$ a finite dimensional subspace, and $y \in X\backslash V$. I try to prove, that there is some $v \in V$ s.t.
$dist(y,V) = \inf_{v \in V} \| y - v\| > 0 $.

I tried the proof via contradiction:

Assume $\forall v \in V: \| y - v \| = 0$. Then $\forall \epsilon >0 \; \exists B(y, \epsilon) \; \text{s.t.} \; v \in B(y, \epsilon)$. Since $V$ is finite dimensional subspace, $V$ is closed, therefore $X\backslash V$ open, so we have $B(y, \epsilon) \subseteq X\backslash V$. Hence $v \in X\backslash V$, but this contradicts to $v \in V$.

Some feedback would be appreciated, whether this goes in the right direction or I have some major issues with my idea.

Comment: Your question seems to have a couple of mistakes. One, yuo say you try to prove that there exists some $v\in V$ such that $dist(y, V)=\inf_{x\in V}\|y-y\|>0$. First of all, the expression does not depend on $v$, did you mean $dist(y, v)$ instead of $dist(y, V)$? Second, $\|y-y\|$ will always be $0$, did you mean $\|x-y\|$?

Comment: Take any $x_0\in V$ and Consider the function $f:x\mapsto\|y-x\|$ on the compact set $K=\{x\in V:\ \|y-x\|\leq \|y-x_0\|\}$. On $V\setminus K$ the distances to $y$ are larger than $\|y-x_0\|$. So, the minimum of $f$ on $K$ is actually minimum of $f$ on $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=d(x,V)$, there exists $x_n\in V$ such that $lim_nd(x_n,x)=d$. This implies that there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $d(x,x_n)<d+1$, we deduce that for $n\geq N$, $d(x_N,x_n)\leq d(x_N,x)+d(x,x_n)<2d+2$ and $(x_n)_{n\geq N}$ is bounded since $V$ is finite dimensional,  there exists a subsequence $x_{n_q}$ of $x_n$ which converges towards $y$. $d(y,x)=d$.

Comment: First thank you. I have some further questions on this answer. Why is it, that there exists such sequence s.t. $\lim_n d(x_n, x) = d$? And how do I conclude that the subsequence converges to $y$, and that we can say $d(y,x) > 0$ at the end?

Comment: $d(x,V)=inf_{y\in V}d(x,y)$. This implies for every $n>0$, there exists $y_n$ such that $d(x,V)\leq d(x,y_n)\leq d(x,V)+{1\over n}$.